# How does overloading function call work in C++?

Tags: c++, struct, overloading, operator-keyword

I read that function call () can also be overloaded. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B

What would the following mean?

It works.

```
template<typename T, typename Comp>
struct bind{
    T v;
    Comp comp;
    bool operator()(const T& b){
        return comp(b,v);
    }
};

int main(){
    bind<int, less<int> > b;
    b.v = 2;
    cout << b(3) << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that if you create an object of type `bind<>`, you can apply the function-call operator to that object.

Like this:

```
bind<int, std::less<int>> b;
b.v = 2;
std::cout << b(1) << "\n";
```

That snippet might print "true" on the standard output.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a class called `foo`, I'm sure you understand what it means to call a member function of an object of that type:

```
foo f;
f.bar();
```

You may also understand that you can overload certain operations. For example, you could overload `operator+` for `foo` so that you could do something like this:

```
foo f, g;
f + g;
```

Now you can also overload `operator()` for a class, which allows you to call it as though it were a function:

```
foo f;
f();
```

Yes, `f` is not a function but it is an object of class type that overloads `operator()`. Class types that do this are known as functors or function objects.

In the example you've given, `bind` is a functor. When you create an object of that type, you can call it like a function, passing it a `const T&` and it will return a `bool` back to you. The implementation of `operator()` actually calls the function stored in `comp`, passing it both the `T` object you passed to `operator()`, `a`, and the member object `v` of type `T`.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>As it stands, it doesn't mean much of anything except "syntax error". For example:</strike>

```
template<T, Op>
```

This simply isn't allowed. For each template parameter, you need to specify whether it's a type (using `class` or `typename`) or a non-type parameter such as an `int`. Since the apparent intent is that both these should be type parameters, you need something like:

```
template <class T, class Op>
```

or:

```
template <typename T, typename Op>
```

For this situation, there's no difference in meaning between `class` and `typename`.

```
struct bind{
    T v;
```

Leaving `v` uninitialized will lead to undefined behavior, so you probably don't want to allow that. You'd normally prevent it by adding a constructor that takes a T as its parameter and initializes `v` to that value:

```
bind(T const &v) : v(v) {}
```

When you include a constructor like this, the compiler won't automatically generate a default constructor, so it's no longer possible to create a `bind` object with `v` uninitialized -- exactly what we wanted.

Although creating the `comp` object:

```
Op comp;
```

is fairly harmless, it's also quite unnecessary. You could just as well do the comparison with a temporary instance created with `Op()`, in which case this:

```
bool operator()(const T& a){
    return comp(a,v);
}
```

...would become something like this (and the `Op comp;` simply removed):

```
bool operator()(T const &a) { 
    return Op()(a, v);
}
```

Even with the corrections, I'd consider this code obsolescent. In C++98/03, it would have been useful in a situation where you needed to supply a functor to an algorithm, such as:

```
std::remove_copy_if(a.begin(), a.end(), bind<int, 
                    std::back_inserter(b),
                    bind<int, std::less<int> >(5));
```

...which would copy numbers from `a` to `b`, removing those less that 5.

In C++11, however, most (if not all) uses of this `bind` should probably be written as lambdas instead though, so the bit above would become something like:

```
std::remove_copy_if(a.begin(), a.end(), bind<int, 
                    std::back_inserter(b),
                    [](int x) { return x < 5; });
```

This is not only shorter, but (at least once you're used to it) quite a bit simpler than using `std::less` and `bind` to put together a function. It won't generally make any difference in run-time efficiency -- a lambda is basically a "shorthand" way of generating a class template, so what it generates would end up pretty similar to the code using `bind`.